# NHibernate: Projecting child entities into parent properties throws an exception

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-projections

I have the following parent entity Department which contains a collection of child entities Sections

```
public class Department  
{
    private Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Section> _sections;
    public Department()
    {
        _sections = new HashedSet<Section>();
    }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Section> Sections
    {
        get { return _sections; }
    }
    public virtual int Version { get; set; }
}

public partial class Section  
{
    public Section()
    {
        _employees = new HashedSet<Employee>();
    }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get;  protected set; }
    public virtual int Version { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to transform (flatten) it to the following DTO

```
public class SectionViewModel
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string  SectionName { get; set; }
}
```

Using the following code.

```
SectionModel sectionModel = null;
Section sections = null;
var result = _session.QueryOver<Department>().Where(d => d.Company.Id == companyId)
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Sections, () => sections)
            .Select(
                    Projections.ProjectionList()
                        .Add(Projections.Property<Department>(d => sections.Department.Name).WithAlias(() => sectionModel.DepartmentName))
                        .Add(Projections.Property<Department>(s => sections.Name).WithAlias(() => sectionModel.SectionName))
                   )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SectionModel>())
            .List<SectionModel>();
```

I am however getting the following exception: **could not resolve property: Department.Name of: Domain.Section**

I have even tried the following LINQ expression

```
        var result = (from d in _session.Query<Department>()
                      join s in _session.Query<Section>()
                          on d.Id equals s.Department.Id into ds
                      from sm in ds.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new SectionModel
                          {
                              DepartmentName = d.Name,
                              SectionName = sm.Name ?? null
                          }).ToList();
```

Mappings

```
public class DepartmentMap : ClassMapping<Department>
{
    public DepartmentMap()
    {           
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
        Property(x => x.Name,
            m =>
            {
                m.Length(100);
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });

        Set(x => x.Sections,
                    m =>
                    {
                        m.Access(Accessor.Field);
                        m.Inverse(true);
                        m.BatchSize(20);
                        m.Key(k => { k.Column("DeptId"); k.NotNullable(true); });
                        m.Table("Section");
                        m.Cascade( Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
                    },
                    ce => ce.OneToMany());
    }
}


public class SectionMap : ClassMapping<Section>
{
    public SectionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, m => m.Generator(Generators.GuidComb));
        Property(x => x.Name,
            m =>
            {
                m.Length(100);
                m.NotNullable(true);
            });
        ManyToOne(x => x.Department,
                m =>
                {
                    m.Column("DeptId");
                    m.NotNullable(true);
                });
    }
}
```

But this throws a **method or operation is not implemented**.

Seeking guidance on what I am doing wrong or missing.

Comment: You're going to need to explicitly join from sections to Departments... Or possibly just select `Departments.Name`. Do you know what the SQL would look like?

Comment: Following is the expected SQL `select d.Name as deptName, s.Name as SectionName from Dept d left join section s on d.id = s.deptid order by d.Name asc, s.Name asc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't know how to access a child property's child through the parent entity. A useful thing to remember about QueryOver is that it gets translated directly into SQL. You couldn't write the following SQL:

```
select [Section].[Department].[Name]
```

right? Therefore you can't do the same thing in QueryOver. I would create an alias for the `Department` entity you start on and use that in your projection list:

```
Department department;
Section sections;    

var result = _session.QueryOver<Department>(() => department)
    .Where(d => d.Company.Id == companyId)
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Sections, () => sections)
    .Select(
            Projections.ProjectionList()
                .Add(Projections.Property(() => department.Name).WithAlias(() => sectionModel.DepartmentName))
                .Add(Projections.Property(() => sections.Name).WithAlias(() => sectionModel.SectionName))
           )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<SectionModel>())
    .List<SectionModel>();
```

I noticed in your comment you'd like an `order by` clause. Let me know if you need help with that and I can probably come up with it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works. I see where I was going wrong. Yes I would like an `order by` but this I can handle. Thanks for the patience and trouble.

Comment: @CallMeKags: No problem! I know QueryOver can be tough to figure out sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This may be now fixed in [3.3.3](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt). Look for

- New Feature
- [NH-2986] - Add ability to include collections into projections

Not sure but if this is your problem specifically but if you are not using 3.3.3 then upgrade and check it out.

Aslo check out the [JIRA](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2986)

Comment: Upgraded to 3.3.3 but the problem persists. Maybe the problem is with the structure of the querying.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a linq query like

```
from d in Departments
from s in d.Sections
select new SectionModel
{
DepartmentName = d.Name,
SectionName = s == null ? String.Empty : s.Name
}
```

Comment: This throws **Specified method is not supported** exception.

Comment: what is the specific linq query you are running?  what do your mappings look like?  I've run queries like this using NH 3.0 and above without a problem.

Comment: Sorry! My mistake. I was calling wrong method for `from d in Departments`. Works but returns an inner join while I am interested in a left join as there are Departments without sections.